# Ошибка авторизации при попытки отправить сообщение от имени сообщества vk

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, http, post, .net-core

Просто пытаюсь отправить сообщение от имени сообщества методом post, но получаю

> "error_code":5,"error_msg":"User authorization failed: no access_token passed."

При этом отправка методом get работает успешно!
Пытался отправлять как из кода, так и просто с помощью различных утилит.

```
var message = new Message()
{
     UserId = 96448509,
     PeerId= 96448509,
     Domain = "kranid",
     RandomId = 2134567654321234,
     Version = 5.92,
     AccessToken = "9746a53ccde445b435a502024c38135201289756d69716f49f973ece422f939447d17d5990b4c68f4e541",
     Text = "hello world!"
};
await  _vkClient.SendMessageAsync(message);

public async Task<string> SendMessageAsync(Message message)
{
     var url = "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send";
     var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<Message>(url, message);
     return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Сам запрос получается такой:

> VK.VkClient:Information: Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send', Version: 2.0, Content: System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`1[VocabularyBot.VK.Message], Headers:
>   {
>     Accept: application/json
>     Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   }
>   VK.VkClient:Information: {"user_id":96448509,"random_id":2134567654321234,"message":"hello world!","access_token":"9746a53ccde445b435a502024c38135201289756d69716f49f973ece422f939447d17d5990b4c68f4e541","v":5.92}

Comment: можете скрин сделать запроса в инспекторе? Может стоит написать как от вас требуют `access_token`?

Comment: Добавил сам запрос.

Comment: [ВК дев](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send) не вижу аргумента access_token. Попробуйте его в хедере передать как auth

Comment: https://m.habr.com/ru/post/265563/ пример на php (удостоверьтесь что все до кода на php вы сделали.

Comment: Я работаю с access_token сообщества, который просто получаю в ручную в сообществе, у меня немного другие действия до кода php в посте. Access_token в запросе есть. Я думаю: может быть нельзя передавать тело запроса в json? Может быть обязательно передавать как данные формы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге проблема была в том, что я пытался отправить именно JSON, а VK принимает данные, либо в виде обычного url, либо в виде multipart/form-data. То есть относительно конкретно netcore и HttpClient, нельзя использовать метод PostAsJsonAsync, а нужно вызывать PostAsync и передавать ему объект FormUrlEncodedContent, который содержит соответствующие данные, ну или использовать просто get запрос, если ненужно отправлять какие-нибудь файлы.